Copy a field for all documents in a collection
I want to be able copy one field to another in a UpdateMany statement.
Something like this:
var updateDef = MongoDB.Driver.Builders<UserStory>
    .Update
    .Set(x => x.SemanticId, x => x.Id);

But the current API doesn't support that.
How can I do something similar with the Csharp driver, i.e., copy a field to another for all documents in the collection? I also need to get an ObjectId generated in a new field.

As far as I can tell, fields cannot be added in C# aggregation pipelines in that way. The workaround seems to be to use a BsonArray/BsonDocument to add the fields. Something like: new BsonArray { new BsonDocument("$set", new BsonDocument("SemanticId", "VALUE")) }. Related: How to use Addfields in MongoDB C# Aggregation Pipeline

Can't be done with the correct collection type, from what I've found..
Must use BsonDocument:
var collection = _mongo.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("SomCollection");
var updateDefinition = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("someField", "$otherField");
var result = collection.UpdateMany(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty, updateDefinition);


does it really work as is?

Close to what @jgauffin provided above, but a bit more good looking:
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var db = client.GetDatabase("db");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Entity>("coll");
        collection.InsertOne(new Entity() { SomeField = "sf", otherFields = "of"});
        var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<Entity>()
            .AppendStage<Entity, Entity, Entity>(
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "$set", new BsonDocument(nameof(Entity.SomeField), $"${nameof(Entity.OtherFields)}") }
                });
        var rendered = pipeline.Render(BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<Entity>(), BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry);
        var updated = collection.UpdateMany(FilterDefinition<Entity>.Empty, pipeline);
        var result = collection.Find("{}").ToList();

